# Data sorting inside n-layered application

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, sorting, architecture

I have the following architecture:

```
DAL (NHibernate) -> BLL -> WCF (http) -> Clients
```

Clients do not know anything about Domain models. WCF comunicates with clients using DTO objects.

One of the clients is a web site (ASP.NET MVC), that has few grids. I need to implement sorting for this grids. Sorting should be implemented on service side, because clients receive only requested part of data (paging).

What is the best way to do this? Now, I have two ways that is not seem to be good.

1. Make for each property of an each entity a separate sort method on service contract (36 in my case)
2. Make generic sort method with tons of reflection and receive magic strings (name of property, direction) from client.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you take a look at OData ?

Comment: Property names are not magic strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the best, in my case, solution - Dynamic LINQ to NHibernate.
http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/11/17/dynamic-linq-to-nhibernate.aspx

```
var elist = session.Query<MyEntity>()
          .OrderBy(“Name descending”)
          .Skip(first)
          .Take(count)
          .ToList();
```

Also, OData seems to be a good way, but I had not time to change the existent project structure.

According to Criteria api - it would be good if it has a way to return`IQueryable` instead of `IList` for compatibility with LINQ. I do not want to use it as default query engine.

Thanks to all. You help me to know something new!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using NHibernate in your DAL, I would suggest passing through the property name to sort by and then using the Criteria api to query the data, you can easily add the property to sort by without using reflection.  I cringe at the thought of having 36 different methods for the same data just to change the sort order...